# enable the "vorbis_parser.h" in ffmpeg build

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, oggvorbis, vorbis

ffmpeg build configuration is such that I have disabled everything and selectively enabled decoders and encoders and demuxers for the formats that I need. I want to use the **vorbis_parser.h** for parsing the extradata, I tried using the **--enable-parser=vorbis** but this does not work. In the include folder of **libavcodec** there shows no file named **vorbis_parser.h**. What option should I set so that I can use **vorbis_parser.h**

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, the `./configure` script for ffmpeg looks like this :

```
./configure --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" \
--extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include" --extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib" \
--bindir="$HOME/bin" --extra-libs="-ldl" --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac \
--enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx \
--enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-x11grab
```

(Source : http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide)

To me it seems like you just have to `--enable-gpl` and `--enable-libvorbis` in your `./configure` script.

Nevertheless there may be options to be enabled and disabled in the libvorbis `./configure` script. I hope this may help.

Have a nice day ;)

Comment: I do not want to use the gpl license nor the option of **--enable-libvorbis**, what I did is **--enable-decoder=vorbis** and **--enable-demuxer=ogg** which works completely fine to fill the avcontext, but I need to use the functions defined in **vorbis_parser.h** to parse the extradata that comes with vorbis. Also the **vorbis_parser.h** has a LGPL license attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the functions beginning with **avpriv** are the private functions of the FFmpeg and those are not included in the header files that are exposed. So probably we cannot include the file **vorbis_parser.h**